# Django: ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54]

Tags: python, django

This logs, quite repeatedly, every time my app loads on my computer.

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 53597)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

I realize that this has been posted on extensively over the years, but it seems to me that the consensus on the answer is that it could be one of a few things:

(a) Using a .png instead of an .ico in a favicon

(b) Misusing {% static %}

(c) Misusing event.preventDefault()

Unfortunately for me, none of those things have happened in the last few weeks in my teams commits. So I ask, are there other solutions I may be missing? This is a result of me recently merging with a master development branch.

Comment: What version of django you are using?

Comment: The problem eventually went away....I couldn't even tell you why @BrunoWego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned [over here](http://I%20had%20this%20problem%20in%20django%20rest%20framework%20while%20using%20pycharm%27s%20code%20editor-based%20http%20client%20to%20debug%20API%20endpoints.%20Setting%20this%20value%20in%20settings.py%20magically%20fixed%20it.), I had this issue show up while debugging POST DRF api endpoints.

The solution was to add `SITE_URL` to settings with my localhost and dev server port set, i.e.

```
SITE_URL = "http://localhost:4000"
```

Commonly this error is associated with a missing favicon file. But I'm not sure if this change gets around that issue or is due to something else.

For added context, I hit this error while using Pycharm's [http request scratch](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html#converting-curl-requests) file to debug and validate DRF (django rest framework) endpoints.

The format I was using was:

```
### Send POST request with json body
POST http://localhost:4000/api/admin/add_node/
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Basic admin password

{
  "name": "node01",
  "username": "username",
  "password": "password"
}
```